# MVC5 DataContext Best Practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In MVC 5 there is a new Identity Class in the models folder. SO let's say I add some additional fields to the user, I would do this in the class

`public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`

Ok, so far so good. I run `add-migration "updatedUser"` and that will update the database.

BUT... Now I want to add a Products, Client and Company Table. Now, some ASP.NET tutorials and Azure tutorials have actually had me setting the getters and setters for each Table inside the ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

But I would think you would not want to inherit from that IdentityDbContext and instead set up a file inside the models folder called:

`DatabaseContext.cs` (For non user/Identity tables)

and do something like:

```
    using MyProject.Domain.Entities;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    namespace MyProject.Models {

    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext 
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

     public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Would this be best practice or should I use the Identity Class? Does it matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you think you would want to do that?

You aren't inheriting anything you aren't already doing because of the ApplicationDbContext supplied.

Adding a second context may make sense in some situations, but chances are you will want to access the Identity fields, and if you are using a different context then you can run into problems with context coherency.

And, FYI, you don't put your DbSet's in the ApplicationDbContext's constructor.

Comment: So your position, then, is most of the time you will only need one datacontext?

Comment: Yeah that was just a typo, fixed it. I kind of understand what your saying. But I'm still a little confused. I went ahead and used ApplicationDBContext for my new tables and most likely I will be wanting to access the identity fields. But I wasn't thinking about not being able to access them from another context. that makes much sense now that I think about it. I'm just a bit confused with all the new methods of doing things in Identity that have changed over the past few (Weeks?) lol big changes (For the better though I can see!)

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I wouldn't go that far.  I would say, however, if you don't know why you need more than one context, you probably don't.  The two biggest reasons would be 1) If you want your applications data in a separate database, or 2) if you have a massively huge set of tables